# Why does qt show () not have priority?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm using Qt for an application.
I would like to display a window then put a timer and display a second window.
But currently the timer is done then the 2 windows open at the same time

```
this->firstWindow->show();
QTime dieTime = QTime::currentTime().addSecs(10);
while (QTime::currentTime() < dieTime);
this->secondWindow->show();
```

I tried a lot of solutions, like putting the show() of the firstwindow directly into the constructor but nothing works.

Comment: You are using a blocking `while` loop to wait for the time to elapse, so the thread cannot update any GUI stuff. You could use `QTimer` for a non-blocking wait or refresh the GUI by adding `qApp->processEvents(QEventLoop::AllEvents, 100)` into your `while` loop. I would prefer `QTimer` because then you are not creating your own event loop. For example, `QTimer::singleShot(10000, this->secondWindow, SLOT(show()));`.

Comment: Ok ! I understood how it works, thank you. It's working with <QTimer>.

Comment: Okay nice. I am turning my comment into an answer, feel free to accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using a blocking `while` loop to wait for the time to elapse, so the GUI thread cannot update the user interface. You could use `QTimer` for a non-blocking wait or refresh the GUI by adding `qApp->processEvents(QEventLoop::AllEvents, 100);` into the `while` loop.

I would prefer `QTimer`, because then you are not creating your own event loop. For example:

```
QTimer::singleShot(10000, this->secondWindow, SLOT(show()));
```